# Interval role i-lines are not displayed in Google line chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am trying to add min and max limits to a Google chart, which I generate using a Perl script from CSV data - by using [the interval role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles) for these 2 values.

Unfortunately the I-lines are not displayed at my line chart, even though I've set the min and max limits to the -100 and 100 for the sake of testing.

Only the main data is being displayed:

[image]

Can anybody please spot the error, what is wrong with my very simple test case?

Please just save the code below as an HTML-file and open in a browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        var data = {"L_B8_ACLR_50_0_QPSK_1_H":{"rows":[
            {"c":[{"v":"UTRA_1_DOWN"},{"v":-100},{"v":100},{"v":"-42.46912"}]},
            {"c":[{"v":"E-UTRA_1_DOWN"},{"v":-100},{"v":100},{"v":"-39.9545"}]},
            {"c":[{"v":"E-UTRA_1_UP"},{"v":-100},{"v":100},{"v":"-48.68408"}]},
            {"c":[{"v":"UTRA_1_UP"},{"v":-100},{"v":100},{"v":"-49.45148"}]},
            {"c":[{"v":"UTRA_2_UP"},{"v":-100},{"v":100},{"v":"-58.96674"}]}],

            "cols":[
            {"p":{"role":"domain"},"label":"MEASUREMENT","type":"string"},
            {"p":{"role":"interval"},"label":"LSL","type":"number"},
            {"p":{"role":"interval"},"label":"USL","type":"number"},
            {"p":{"role":"data"},"label":"1142926087","type":"number"}]}};

        function drawCharts() {
                for (var csv in data) {
                        var x = new google.visualization.DataTable(data[csv]);

                        var options = {
                                title: csv,
                                width: 800,
                                height: 600
                        };

                        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(csv));
                        chart.draw(x, options);
                }
        }

        $(function() {
                google.setOnLoadCallback(drawCharts);
        });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="L_B8_ACLR_50_0_QPSK_1_H"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

(I don't want to use methods like `addColumn` or `addRows`. Instead I prepare my data as data structure in my Perl script and then JSON-encode and pass it to `DataTable` ctr).

Comment: This is incredibly odd -- your syntax seems to be dead on, and I can't see any issue after fiddling around with it and digging through the docs. Have you tried creating the same object using the `addRows` and `addColumns` methods, and compared it to the one your code creates to see if you can spot the difference? After all, they should end up as the same object. It's possible this could be a mistake on the Google side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the interval-role column after the data-column. As written in the [API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#rolehierarchy) :

"*All columns except domain columns apply to the nearest left neighbor to which it can be applied*"

So if you change the order (and here with some smaller intervals)

```
var data = {"L_B8_ACLR_50_0_QPSK_1_H":{"rows":[
            {"c":[{"v":"UTRA_1_DOWN"},{"v":"-42.46912"},{"v":-50},{"v":-45}]},
            {"c":[{"v":"E-UTRA_1_DOWN"},{"v":"-39.9545"},{"v":-50},{"v":-45}]},
            {"c":[{"v":"E-UTRA_1_UP"},{"v":"-48.68408"},{"v":-50},{"v":-45}]},
            {"c":[{"v":"UTRA_1_UP"},{"v":"-49.45148"},{"v":-50},{"v":-45}]},
            {"c":[{"v":"UTRA_2_UP"},{"v":"-58.96674"},{"v":-50},{"v":-45}]}],

            "cols":[
            {"p":{"role":"domain"},"label":"MEASUREMENT","type":"string"},
            {"p":{"role":"data"},"label":"1142926087","type":"number"},
            {"p":{"role":"interval"},"label":"LSL","type":"number"},
            {"p":{"role":"interval"},"label":"USL","type":"number"}
            ]}};
```

..You end up with :

[image]